# I can't add rows or columns in Extracted Google spreadsheet from BigQuery?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make a simple program using google spreadsheet and BigQuery.

I extracted a BigQuery data into Google spreadsheet.

I was thinking to add a column between the extracted table sheet colums, but i think it is banned.

Does anyone knows how to add columns between the extracted table sheet columns? Which user can add some informations like ordinary excel cell.

I already tried to make a blank cell in SQL(Select blank as null) but I can't edit that cell when i extract the table to the google spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the spreadsheet: You can make a copy of the extracted spreadsheet and modify the copy as needed. To make a copy, go to "File" -> "Make a copy" in the Google Sheets menu.